# Best workflow for software development with many release versions

Tags: git, version-control, github, workflow

We are currently changing our workflow with Git to avoid the maximum of errors and regressions...

I read this one: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

To make a short summary:

- The **master** branch has a tag representing the production version.
- The **develop** branch is where the next release is prepared. It is the branch where the tests are run every night. And the branch for the nightly build.
- **Feature-Something** branch where the features for the next are made, and merged at the end on the *develop* branch. This branch should be in developers repositories only.
- **Fix-Something** branch where the Hot fixes are made, can be merged on *develop* and *master*
- The **Release-1.2** branch is where the next release is prepared with the last fix and changes are made. It is merged on *master* and *development* when it is ready for production.

I really like it, but it seems there are one or two things incompatible with some of our requirements:

- First, our software has clients on the **1.0** version for example and some on **1.2**. We are not migrating the client from the 1.0 onto the 1.2 for the simple fact that we are not supporting Unity 3.4 any more on the later version. But some of our clients are still using it.

But now, imagine that we found a bug in the core of our product, and we have to fix it for every version. It seems complicated to do this with this workflow without duplicating commits...

We thought about something like:

[image: Git workflow]

With this new *modified* workflow when fixes are applicable on every production branches, we just have to merge it onto every branch. That is why we thought about to have a branch by the main release version.

But is that a good workflow? What are the cons of this workflow? The pros? I think it can be a bit confusing...

- The other point I think not compatible with this workflow is the `pull- request`. We want to use a `pull-request` system, that is, when someone finishes a feature or fixes a bug, he has to make a pull request on the branches he wants to make his work merged on it.

But I was wondering - *as explained in the article linked* - if the fact that every branch for *features* or *bugs* should only be on the developer computer makes the use of the pull-request impossible? I think we have to push the branch on *GitHub* before requesting a *pull-request*, right?

Finally, what do you think about this workflow? Is it fine for a small team of 4-10 developers? Do you have any suggestions to make it better? Do you have a better workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'll have to maintain two parallel stable branches. While git makes branching reasonably easy, maintaining parallel versions of your software consumes significant resources. Expect this to be painful in any case.

Some general hints concerning this scenario:

- Estimate the lifespan of the two parallel stable branches. The longer they live, the more effort it will cost you in the end.
- Think about how much activity you expect on which of the branches. In particular, is the 1.0 series just for the occasional importand bug fix, or will there be significant development activity there. In the latter case, you should try to keep both branches as close to each other as you possibly can.

I can imagine two variants:

- 1.0.x only gets rare important bugfixes. Then, the develop branch should be essentially close to 1.2 and merged in there on every 1.2 release, and you can cherry-pick the rare bugfixes back directly to the 1.0 branch.
- 1.0.x gets significant features. Then you should develop those features on a branch that is actually close to 1.0.x. This could be a separate develop branch.

Before embarking on an overly complex branching model (which may easily confuse the team), be sure to also read [this article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureBranch.html).